# Alternative Bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to its finite subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

There are different proofs for the fact that there's a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to the set of all its finite subsets, but I would like to know if this explicit bijection does work, too.

$f:\mathbb{N} \to P_{inf}(\mathbb{N})$, $f(0)=\{\}$ $f(n)=
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \{k\}  & \mbox{if } n = 2^k \\
  \{k\} \bigcup f(n-2^k) & \mbox{else.}
 \end{array}
\right.$ , where $k:=2^k\leq n\leq 2^{k+1}$

The inverse is just built up the other way around.

My proof for this is rather unpleasant and long, but could this work in general or is this one similar to another proof?

Let me know if important information is missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So a number with binary representation $2^{n_1}+2^{n_2}+\cdots+2^{n_d}$ represents the set $\{n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_d\}$? Looks good to me.

Comment: @Rahul: If that's the function, then it's just the inverse of the usual function $f(A)=\sum_{n\in A}2^n$, where $A$ is a finite subset of $\Bbb N$.

Comment: So, is it related to one of these: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Set_of_Finite_Subsets_of_Countable_Set_is_Countable ?